# optionally enclosed not working, commas breaking upload

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    trans_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    spend decimal(10,2),
    impressions int,
    PRIMARY KEY (trans_id)
);
```

Here is my load statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/my_file.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(spend, impressions);
```

In `spend` I'll have a decimal value with a comma like: 1193.72.

The `spend` field gets uploaded as 1. The `impressions` field that follows is correct and unaffected.

Example record: 1/19/2021 | 1,193.72 | 92780

Output: 1/19/2021 | 1 | 92780

I was under the impression including `optionally enclosed by '"'` would solve this, and for other text fields it seems to work as expected, but here it's causing me problems.

Comment: A CSV string like `"1,2,3"` cannot be stored in an integer column.  Maybe include a few representative lines from `my_file.csv`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added an example record and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support input of numeric literals formatted with thousands separators.

The best solution would be to pre-process your input file before you try to use LOAD DATA INFILE. Otherwise you could do this workaround:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/my_file.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@tmp_spend, impressions)
SET spend = REPLACE(@tmp_spend, ',', '');
```

This stores the spend value into a temporary variable, instead of directly into the column. A user-defined variable is always a string type. Then you can remove the commas from that string before assigning it to the numeric spend column.